# SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'TEST' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to insert some values into my table which is created of executing this query

```
public static final String tableName = "ACCOUNT_TABLE"; 

statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE "+ tableName +" (" +
   " ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ("+
   " START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), username VARCHAR(15), password VARCHAR(100)" + ")");
```

after that when table were created successfully, I'm calling register method to insert user into table

```
public boolean registerAccount(final User user){
    if (statement != null){
        final String userName = user.getUserName();
        final String password = user.getPassword();
        try {
            return statement.execute("INSERT INTO "+tableName +" VALUES (" + userName +"," + password +")");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

at this example userName == "TEST" and password == "123"

here 
 `return statement.execute("INSERT INTO "+tableName+" VALUES (" + userName +"," + password +")");`
 throws exception

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'TEST' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'TEST' is not a column in the target table.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You miss the single quotes arrount the values. But better you learn about prepared Statements, to prevent SQL injection and these kind of errors

Comment: use this instead `statement.execute("INSERT INTO "+tableName +" VALUES ('" + userName +"','" + password +"')");`

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement`. Do **not** concatenate values into the SQL string. Not only will it prevent SQL injection but it will also fix the problem you have right now.

Comment: Thanks that worked, now I'm getting this error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns.

Comment: Why I'm getting this error? table has 3 column which one of them is auto incriment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Strings should be between two `'username'` so your query should look like this `statement.execute("INSERT INTO "+tableName +" VALUES ('" + userName +"','" + password +"')");`
2. But this is not secure, to avoid any Syntax error or SQL Inject, you have to use PreparedStatement instead.
3. about this error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException` this happen because you don't specify which columns you want to insert in your query, so it should look like this :

```
    INSERT INTO tableName(username_col, password_col) VALUES ('userName', 'password')
    //-----------------------^-------------^----------------------^-----------^
```